# How to find itemset2 eclat in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

This is my query for finding `itemset1`, how to find `itemset2`?

```
public function ajaxList()
    {
        $penjualan = Penjualan::select(DB::raw('TIDList as TIDList, material as material'))->groupBy('material')->get();
        $data = array();
        foreach($penjualan as $row)
        {
            $tidlist = DB::table('penjualans')
                        ->select(DB::raw('TIDList as TIDList'), 'material')
                        ->where('material', $row->material)
                        ->get();
            $data2 = array();
            foreach($tidlist as $line)
            {
                $data2[] = $line->TIDList;
            }

            $data[] = [
                'material' => $row->material,
                'TIDList' => implode(', ', $data2)
            ];
        }
        $datatables = DataTables::of($data);
        return $datatables->addIndexColumn()
            ->make(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `itemset1` in your code?

Comment: for example the eclat algorithm classifies the transactions that appear into 1 based on the items purchased. This grouping means itemset1. for itemset2, grouping two transactions into one based on the goods purchased